# How to get the lines that contain -R with grep

Tags: grep

How can I find "-R" in files with grep? 
I tried `grep "-R" *.GNU` to get the lines that contain -R, but it returns nothing.

Comment: A similar question was asked on [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427913/how-can-i-grep-for-a-string-that-begins-with-a-dash). You can find some useful answers and examples there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
grep -- -R *.GNU
```

The `--` indicates end of options so that `-R` is seen as an argument instead of an option to `grep`

Answer (score 5):

A fair amount of the GNU tools support an option where you can tell the tool (`rm`, `grep`, `ls`, etc.) that you no longer want it to continue parsing for command line options to itself. This option is facilitated by marking the command line input with a double dash `--`.

You can read more about it in the [GNU CoreUtils FAQ](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/coreutils-faq.html). Specifically this section, titled: [11 How do I remove files that start with a dash](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/faq/#How-do-I-remove-files-that-start-with-a-dash_003f).

This allows for files that begin with a dash (i.e. `-`) to be passed as command line arguments:

#### examples

```
rm ./-stuff
rm /full/path/-stuff
rm -- -stuff

mv ./-stuff differentstuff
mv -- -stuff differentstuff
```

Comment: That's not GNU specific though. That's POSIX. It's not _all_ the tools (see for instance `test` or `echo`). Also note that with `find`, `--` stops filenames from being taken as options, but not from being taken as predicates.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - Yes I was afraid when I stated *all* that I was overstating it but I believe it to be most, or at least all that make use of the `coreutils` package. If I run the following command under Fedora, `rpm -q --whatrequires coreutils -l` I get a list of all the files that require it and it's a pretty large chunk of the GNU tools from what I can tell. Thanks for the clarification on `find`, yet another thing I wasn't aware of 8-).

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -e -R ./*.GNU
```

is another possibility.

Comment: @stephane sure, but that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 3):

**The most common ways**

`grep -- -R *.GNU` works with some variants of grep. The `--` tells grep to stop looking for flags.

`grep -e -R *.GNU` works as well. The `-e` tells grep that a search pattern follows.

**Alternatives**

```
grep '[-]R' *.GNU
```

`[-]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Since there's only one character in the class, it must match a hyphen (`-`).

```
grep '.\?-R' *.GNU
```

The question mark tells grep that the character prior to it is optional. The `.` matches any character.

```
grep '\(\)-R' *.GNU
```

The parenthesis make an empty [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Comment: +1 for encouraging creativity. There is more than one way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping the dash like

```
grep "\-R" *.GNU
```

Comment: Technically, that works as long as `\-` is not recognised as an extended regexp operator by your `grep` implementation. The backslash doesn't escape the `-` as far as the regexp is concerned (neither `-` nor `\-` are special so the backslash is ignored), but because now the first argument to `grep` doesn't start with a `-`, it escapes the `-` in the sense that it's no longer causing the argument to be taken as an option. `grep '[-]R'` or `grep '\(-R\)'` would also work. You'd still need a `--` with GNU grep if some filenames may start with `-`.